# How can I change uipanel dimensions by using user input?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to change panel and axes width and height values by using user input. These values will represent a photograph's resolution. For example, if a user inputs `512*512`, the `uipanel` and `Axes`' width and height will change to `512` and the user will work on this workspace.

What I tried so far:

```
prompt = {'Enter width', 'Enter height'}; 
dlg_title = 'Input'; num_lines = 1; def = {'256','256'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def); 
uipanel1.width = str2num(answer{1}); 
uipanel1.height = str2num(answer{2});
```

but the size of `uipanel1` does not change.

Comment: can you post what you already tried ?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly the problem that you face with. How do you get the user's input? how you try to adjust the axes and panel sizes?

Comment: I'm taking the user input like this, but uipanel1.width and uipanel1.height dont change the value

prompt={'Enter width','Enter height' };
dlg_title='Input';
num_lines=1;
def={'256','256'};
answer=inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
uipanel1.width=str2num(answer{1});
uipanel1.height=str2num(answer{2});

Comment: Which version of MATLAB (or `hg`) are you using? Also, please include the clarification you added as a comment in the question itself (there's an `edit` button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that demonstrates how what you want can be done, which works with [matlab-hg2](/questions/tagged/matlab-hg2) (default from MATLAB 2014b and onward).

```
%% //Create a figure with a uipanel & axes
hFig = figure('Units','pixels');       %// Create a new figure
hFig.Position = [100 100 600 600];     %// Adjust figure's position
hPan = uipanel(hFig,'Units','pixels'); %// Create a new panel
hPan.Position = [150 150 300 300];     %// Adjust panel's position
hAx = axes('Parent',hPan,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1]); %// New axes
%% //Ask for user input
prompt = {'Enter width', 'Enter height'}; 
dlg_title = 'Input'; num_lines = 1; def = {'256','256'};
answer = cellfun(@str2double,inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def)); 
%% //Modify the panel's position (axes will stretch\shrink automatically to fit)
hPan.Position(3:4) = answer;
```

On older versions of MATLAB, you may need slightly different steps:

```
new_pos_vec = get(hPan,'Position'); %// Get the existing values
new_pos_vec(3:4) = answer;          %// Modify just the width & height
set(hPan,'Position', new_pos_vec);  %// Update graphical properties
```

Comment: I have a question about your answer, when i use this code i took this error message: "conversion to double from struct is not possible" in using axes. How can i eliminate this error?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? On which line did it happen? Was it the one with `axes`? Check this out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html

Comment: 2012a version i am using. in this " hax = axes('Parent', hp,'Units', 'pixels', %'Position',[250 250 1 1]);" line im taking this error

Comment: @user2111190 As I mentioned in the very beginning, my code was not intended for such old versions of MATLAB (or handle graphics, to be precise). You have two options: either follow [these](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update#testing) instructions to force MATLAB to use HG2, or replace the lines `hFig.Position...` and `hPan.Position...` with `set(hFig,'Position',....)` etc. like I demonstrated in the 2nd code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `set`command to modify the UI component properties (and `get` command to retrieve information). In your case:

```
% get current position
currentPosition = get(uipanel1, 'position');

% update the position with the entered values
set(uipanel1, 'position', [currentPosition(1), currentPosition(2), str2num(answer{1}), str2num(answer{2})]);
```